# Expected ')' (using netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

```
try {

    if (txtID.getText().isEmpty()
            || txtLname.getText().isEmpty()
            || txtFname.getText().isEmpty()
            || txtMname.getText().isEmpty()
            || jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()
            || jTextField2.getText().isEmpty()
            || jTextField3.getText().isEmpty())

    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill Up All The Fields");
    } else {
        if (btnReg.getText().equals("REGISTER")) {
            stm.execute("insert into tblregular(ID, LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, VLEAVE, SLEAVE, TOTAL) values"
                            + "('" + txtID.getText().trim() + "'"

                            + ",'" + txtLname.getText().trim().toUpperCase() + "'"
                            + ",'" + txtFname.getText().trim().toUpperCase() + "'"
                            + ",'" + txtMname.getText().trim().toUpperCase() + "'"
                            + ",'" + jTextField1.getText().trim().toUpperCase() + "'"
                            + ",'" + jTextField2.getText().trim().toUpperCase() + "'"
                            + ",'" + jTextField3.getText().trim().toUpperCase() + "'"


                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration Successfull");
        } else {
            txtID.setText("");
            txtLname.setText("");
            txtFname.setText("");
            txtMname.setText("");
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
            txtMname.setText("");

        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

In the line `+ ",'"+jTextField3.getText().trim().toUpperCase()+"'"`- it says `Expected ')'` what is my error there? what to do, what to add, what to remove, i can't help my self out. please help me out.

Comment: So this is a good reason why you shouldn't use string concatenation to build a query - not only is it susceptible to SQL injection, it can lead to headaches like this.

Comment: because in my college, this is what they teach sir. what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: I agree with netbeans, you should close the brackets that you have opened

Comment: you have not closed execute method bracket

Comment: in what line, and what shall i have to do? please make an example :( thank you

Answer (score 3):

you have not closed the bracket of execute method.

```
stm.execute("insert into tblregular(ID, LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, VLEAVE, SLEAVE, TOTAL) values"
                        + "('"+txtID.getText().trim()+"'"

                        + ",'"+txtLname.getText().trim().toUpperCase()+"'"
                        + ",'"+txtFname.getText().trim().toUpperCase()+"'"
                        + ",'"+txtMname.getText().trim().toUpperCase()+"'"
                        + ",'"+jTextField1.getText().trim().toUpperCase()+"'"
                        + ",'"+jTextField2.getText().trim().toUpperCase()+"'"
                        + ",'"+jTextField3.getText().trim().toUpperCase()+"'");
```

and try to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and here is the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1):

you need to complete the string you are passing to stm.execute() as well as the semicolon needed after that statement. that string is missing a closing paren for the values of the insert..